# Render SVG file and display annotation on top of SVG file in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, svg, annotations

I want to render the SVG file in iOS application, parse the coordinates data and display the annotation on top of SVG image based on coordinates (something similar to display annotation on `MKMapView` with pins based on lat/long).

I came across 2 approaches:

1. Use `UIWebView`: The `UIWebView` does display my SVG file perfectly. And then I might use HTML parser to get the coordinates. But then I am not sure how to put annotations on top of web view so that when user zoom or pan the image, the annotation will not get disturbed like map view.
2. Use `SVGKit`: I have downloaded [`SVGKit`](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit/), and then tried rendering my SVG file. Some part of SVG image is not rendered properly.

Any help or directions would be much appreciated.

Thanks.